# Error when using (case and len) in where statement

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I am trying to write a stored procedure to extract data from one of column based on the value of `@acc_id`.

As you can see I get an error on `where CASE (len(acc_id) > 8 then client_id ELSE client_acc end)`

But I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I would be very grateful for any assistance.

```
create procedure test_client @acc_id nvarchar(20)
as
Select 
    client_id,
    cash_t.client_acc,
    sub_trans_type,
    settle_date,
    dbt_crt,
    cash_t.currency,
    cash_amount,
    cash_t.last_update
    From test_cash_trans as cash_t

    inner join client_crm as crm
    on cash_t.client_acc = crm.client_acc

    where crm.client_acc in (
    select  client_acc
    from client_crm
    where CASE (len(acc_id) > 8 then client_id ELSE client_acc end) 
    )
    order by crm.client_acc ASC
GO
```

Result:

> 11:31:47 Started executing query at Line 104 Msg 102, Level 15, State
> 1, Procedure test_client, Line 20 Incorrect syntax near '>'. Total
> execution time: 00:00:00.010

Comment: Don't use `case` in `where` clauses. What should it do anyway?

Comment: The `WHERE` doesn't make sense. The `CASE` has too many parenthesis, but even after you fix that, it's not a boolean expression. What should the `CASE` expression equal? What you have would be like saying `WHERE (len(acc_id) > 8 AND client_id) OR (len(acc_id) <= 8 AND client_acc)`. `AND client_id` *what*?

Comment: You `CASE` expression is syntactically incorrect. It should be `CASE WHEN len(acc_id) > 8 then .. END`.  This is why you get the error message.

Comment: Do you want to use a different ID from the `client_crm` table, based on the lebgtf of  `@acc_id`. if so, you need a different `WHERE` clause. And, where do you use `@acc_id`?

Comment: apologies I am new to sql, so if my understanding is off please forgive me.  Basically @acc_id could be either a client_id or an client_acc.  if the length of acc_id is greater than 8 then acc_id is a client_id otherwise it is an client_acc.  I am then using either the client_id or client_acc to work out the list of accounts for the query to return

Comment: Typically a column with a name containing "ID" is numeric. If so, logic based on the length of a numeric value is unusual and rare. It might also be based on an assumption that is not guaranteed It is also a bad idea to use a single parameter for different things. Don't write confusing code that will be difficult to adjust in the future. Use 2 different parameters so there can be no possible confusion. And

Comment: And, of course, you also did not reference your parameter correctly in your query. Lastly, you have developed a bad habit. ALWAYS include the alias name when referring to any column in your query. Consistent code writing is a good habit to develop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a different `WHERE` clause. Probably the reason for this misunderstanding is the fact, that in T-SQL `CASE` is an expression, not a "control-of-flow" language element.

```
WHERE 
   (
      (LEN(@acc_id) > 8) AND (crm.client_acc in (SELECT client_id FROM client_crm))
   ) OR
   (
      (LEN(@acc_id) <= 8) AND (crm.client_acc in (SELECT client_acc FROM client_crm))
   )
```